# Cannot create a document on firebase

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have been updating my firestore rules and the simulator works as expected but for some reason when i create a new document i get insufficient permissions error

Here are the firebase rules

```
match /users/{usersid} {
        allow read, update, get: if request.auth.uid == usersid
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != usersid

    }
```

And here is how i am trying to add a document

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}
    this.afs.doc(`users/${user['user'].uid}`).set(data, {merge: true}).then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
```

So my Question is are the rules OK? or is it to do with the way i am creating a document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the fix was the rule for the create wasn't allowing it so i just added it to the same rule as the other

```
allow read, update, get, create: if request.auth.uid == usersid
```

and that allowed it to work again